# Generalização em Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Estou modelando um trabalho, esbarrei numa situação que desconheço a forma de proceder:

Em uma clinica Médica, uma PESSOA pode ser FÍSICA ou JURÍDICA.
O PACIENTE, pode ser apenas PESSOA FÍSICA

Aqui vem a dúvida:

O Responsável Financeiro(RespFin) pode ser pessoa FÍSICA ou JURÍDICA, desde que não seja ambos simultaneamente:

[image: Modelagem atual]

Como posso dizer para o BrModelo que RespFin é uma generalização tanto de Física quanto de Jurídica e não simultâneo?
Que tipo de Generalização é essa?

Comment: eu acho que está meio confuso. Tanto paciente quanto responsável financeiro são PESSOAS, apenas são dois tipos diferentes de pessoas. precisa ter uma tabela específica para cada um? Se precisa, eu faria as duas tabelas como especializações da tabela pessoa.

Comment: Boa tarde Washington, fiz as tabelas especificas pois pessoa fisica tem muitos atributos que a juridica nao pode ter, assim como a fisica nao pode ter cnpj.

Comment: Talvez possa resolver com herança múltipla de entidade. Dá uma olhada [nessa apostila](https://profandreagarcia.files.wordpress.com/2018/05/banco-de-dados-cap-7-pg-24.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

No seu modelo de classes, RespFin irá derivar de Pessoa apenas. Pessoa automaticamente será ou Física ou Juridica, conforme você mesmo quer. A implementação em RespFin quase por certo terá que ser override sobre a herança.